# how to commit changes to a drupal project

Tags: git, drupal, drupal-7

i've issue understanding the module releasing system in drupal, it's really confusing me.

i have a project published on drupal.org, whenever i make change i had to commit and add a new tag, because git won't allow me to push on a detached head.

i need i way to commit changes to '7.x-1.0' which is a tag, now i read that a tag is just a reference to a specific commit, how i can commit a change to specific tag without creating a new tag for it? and why drupal uses the tagging system instead of branching ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git push origin <commit-ish>:refs/heads/foo
```

Here "commit-ish" is a valid [git revision](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) that points to a commit object. It can be `HEAD`, a tag, a specific commit, a branch and etc.

For example, if you'd like to push the detached HEAD to create or update `foo`:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/foo
```

or

```
git push origin HEAD:foo
```

The detached HEAD should come from a branch. If it comes from a tag, the tag should come from a branch. You could check what branches the remote repository has via `git ls-remote -h`. Find out the branch that you can work with.